# Packet capture on wireless network (libpcap)

Tags: networking, wireless, libpcap, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I have a small home network that I would like to analyze and capture the traffic on. What are my options for doing this? Ultimately, I would like to use a packet capture library, such as libpcap, to sniff the network in real-time as my router receives packets. I'm mainly interested in HTTP traffic. Thus far, when I run my program, I only seem to be able to see packets sourced or destined to my machine. Is there a way that I may inspect any traffic that travels through my wireless modem/router?

From the research I've done, it seems that the only way this is possible is through [ARP poisoning](http://thexploit.com/sec/sniffing-traffic-on-your-home-network/) or using a CISCO router that features [Embedded Packet Capture](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/iosswrel/ps6537/ps6555/ps9913/datasheet_c78-502727.html).

Has anyone tried either of these and how successful were you? Are these my only options or is there something I may have overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

Hi :) I think ARP poisoning and so on is not so easy to drop in.. ;) but you could start by trying one of the most famous network packets analyzer: Wireshark. Networking is very far to be easy.. :P but Wireshark will help you a lot and, btw, supports also libcap. Hope that helps :)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. I'm not looking for a software suite but rather something that I can develop my own software with.